# Need Immediate Help for Kubuntu installation

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, bootloader

I am very new for Kubuntu and other Linux OS.
I tried to install Kubuntu through my Pen drive
and got some error message while installing here you can find error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/kde_components/Keyboard.py", line
176, in paintEvent x, rw = drawRow(keys[i], x, y, i == 1 and not
ext_return) File
"/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/kde_components/Keyboard.py", line
138, in drawRow rect, Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignBottom,
self.regular_text(k)) File
"/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/kde_components/Keyboard.py", line
223, in regular_text return self.codes[index - 1][0] IndexError: list
index out of range
```

please help me to install Kubuntu correctly how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue because of the keyboard I was using. My timezone is Sri Lanka and it detected a phonetic keyboard which is not compatible with my laptop keyboard. So I changed my timezone to US and the installation proceeded successfully.

If you have a US keyboard change your timezone to United State region that detects a US keyboard and install. You can change it afterwards.